# GCP Service Account Key Rotation

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am trying to implement Key Rotation for GCP Service Accounts. I have managed to create a new key and then decode the `privateKeyData` which is base64 encoded, which has the actual SA JSON file. Now when I am reading the file back to authenticate, it is giving me this error:

> 'unicode object has no iterKeys()'

Issue is with `json.dumps` I think.

```
data = base64.b64decode(key['privateKeyData']).decode('utf-8')
print data  # this prints expected output


with open('file.json', mode='w') as out:
    str = json.dumps(data)
    print out  # this adds \n,\\ to the output
    out.write(str)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

Dummy Snippet of how the file is being converted after `json.dumps`:

```
"{\n  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n  \"project_id\": \"testproj\",\n  \"private_key_id\": \6866996939\"}"\n
```

Answer (score 1):

The `json.dumps()` function is usually used to turn a `dict` into a string representing JSON:

```
>>> json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

But you're giving it a string instead, which is causing it to escape the quotes:

```
>>> json.dumps('{"foo": "bar"}')
'"{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}"'
```

You should just write `data` to the file instead:

```
with open('file.json', mode='w') as out:
    out.write(data)
```

It seems you might have a second problem that is causing the exception, you should include the full traceback in your answer, instead of just the last line.